# Please undelete my question

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have asked a question about resource recommendation. The question is

https://music.stackexchange.com/q/29442/18684

I know that questions about resource recommendation are not allowed on some stack exchange sites. The reason why resource recommendation questions are not allowed is because they tend to ask a big list of references which attracts spam. But my question is quite specific and I only need one answer. I am not asking about a list of references. I've myself found some good articles on wikipedea. The problem is that I am not finding a detailed scientific article which would start from scratch. I've started to read about *scales*. But I am not finding satisfactory explanation. E.g. why do overtones of a fundamental frequency sound alike, how was the *scale* system invented or discovered. I've found useful answer on quora, e.g. [this](http://www.quora.com/Music-Theory/Why-do-pitches-separated-by-an-octave-sound-the-same).

I've seen some questions about resource recommendation on this website which are not even undeleted but are not-closed too, [first](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1439/18684), [second](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2084/18684), [third](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/11313/18684). I've also seen some soft question for advice, e.g. [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/9792/18684).

I can change the wording of the question to make it a advice-seeking question rather than a specific resource recommendation type question. I am not asking a bug-list question. There are similar questions which are allowed. If my question has to be closed, then at least please undelete it. I've asked the same questions on quora, [here](http://www.quora.com/How-is-rap-different-from-usual-music) and [here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-learn-the-science-behind-the-music). I am also giving the links in my profile. If my question got undeleted here, someone could go to my profile and if I be lucky he/she may give me answer on quora.

I in noway am disrespecting other users and moderator's decision to close and delete my question. I am just requesting to at least undelete it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I should add that I deleted your question because of the extended discussion occurring in the comments.  Meta is the place for such discussion, so thanks for bringing it here.

---

Recommendations aren't off-topic because they *ask for* an unsortable list of subjective one liners.  It's because they *receive* such answers.  What about your question would prevent this?  Please see https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/162/28 for more detail.

Stack Exchange is for specific questions.

> why do overtones of a fundamental frequency sound alike, how was the scale system invented or discovered

Why don't you ask these specific questions instead of asking something you know is off-topic?

If you see other off-topic questions, you can flag them (or vote to close once you get more reputation).  They do not justify adding more off-topic questions.

Comment: 1. Not all SE sites disallow recommendation questions, e.g. Math.SE. 2. Why don't I ask those specific question is that because there are many and I know I am not able to understand the would-be answers, until I learn the elementary concepts of music. What I am asking is that at least do not delete it unilaterally.3. It seems like there are double standards when other similar questions are not even closed and my question is deleted.

Comment: @user31782 1. What other sites do isn't relevant to us. 2. If you don't know the answers how could you possibly know you won't understand them?  You know enough to ask the questions.... 3. I'm afraid we don't have a perfect, omniscient closure-bot scouring every question every day.  Things fall through the cracks.  I refer to the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to Matthew's point, from your questions so far it does seem like you haven't spent enough time to see what sort of questions work here. You may have a very specific question, but if it isn't in our scope then it will still get closed.

That said, your question really is not specific - it is seems to be a list of questions broadly connected to the topic, but not structured, not specific and not on-topic (in the main)

So I'd suggest a re-read of our site scope (click on that help button up at the top of the page) and browsing questions that have a high score here.

And last but not least, remember, everyone here is a volunteer - be polite and respectful, accept comments from the community, update your question rather than write extended comment threads, and it will be easier for the community to help you. If you make it difficult they will move on and answer someone else's questions.